# Really long request with no reply

Tags: apache2, php, codeigniter

In the app I work on, we have an "export from highrise" feature that produces a .csv file.

Sometimes (depending on the things we need exported) the request takes a long time (7-10 minutes). Everything work fine (as far as I can tell) server side but my client's browser (he tried safari, chrome and firefox) doesn't get a response. Aka the browser just stays there with the loading animation indefinitely (well we gave up after 45 minutes).

On my machine everything works fine on all browsers. Based on the logs I have/put in place, everything goes as plan, the task ends the output is sent, but he gets no response.

Any idea is welcome, I have no idea where to look next.

EDIT: I did what @ceejayoz suggested but the problem persists, the browser doesn't receive a response, it just sits there waiting even though the file is generated correctly.

Comment: This question (as it stands anyway) sounds more like a programming question, so I voted for it to go to stackoverflow as it sounds more like a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have the export generate server-side, and have the user-facing page refresh or check via AJAX every 15-30 seconds to see if the export is complete. Once completed, redirect them to the file.

Comment: Man... that is obvious. I'll try that. Anyway the problem still remains, why doesn't his browser gets the response.